# If $A$ belongs to the tail $ \sigma $-algebra generated by $(A_k)$ then there is a sequence $P( E_n \,\triangle\,A)\to 0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

*Note: in the following the notation $ \sigma (S)$ means "$ \sigma $-algebra generated by $S$".*

This is an exercise of the graduate probability textbook of Allan Gut. Let $(A_k)$ a sequence of independent events and set

$$
\mathcal{A}_n:= \sigma (\{A_1,\ldots ,A_n\}), \quad \mathcal{A}'_n:= \sigma (\{A_{n+1},\ldots \})
$$

Then the tail $ \sigma $-algebra generated by $(A_k)$ is defined by $\mathcal{T}:= \bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}\mathcal{A}'_n$. Then it is asked to show that if $A\in \mathcal{T}$ then there exists a sequence $(E_k)$ such that $E_k\in \mathcal{A}_k$ for each $k\in {\mathbb N}$ and $\lim_{k\to \infty }P(A \,\triangle\,E_k)=0$.

Gut says that this is a slight elaboration of lemma 3.1, who says that if $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra and $A\in \sigma (\mathcal{F})$ then for every $ \epsilon >0$ there is some $A_ \epsilon \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $P(A \,\triangle\,A_{\epsilon })< \epsilon $.

Im really stuck with this exercise, I dont see a way to prove the statement. It is clear that we can find some sequence $(E_k)\subset \mathcal{T}$ with the desired properties, that is $ \lim_{k\to \infty }P(A \,\triangle\,E_k)=0$, but I dont have any idea about how continue. I need some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A \in \mathcal T$ and $k \geq 1$. Then $A \in \mathcal A_k'$. Note that $\bigcup_{n\geq k} \sigma (X_k,X_{k+1},...,X_n)$ is an algebra which generates $\mathcal A_k'$. Hence there exists $n_k$ and  $F_k \in \sigma (X_k,X_{k+1},...,X_{n_k})$ such that $P(A \Delta F_k) <\frac 1 k$. Note that $F_k \in \sigma (X_1,X_2,...,X_{n_k})$. The only problem now is we don't have $n_k=k$. But that is not a serious problem. Define a new sequence $(E_k)$ as follows: for $n_k \leq n < n_{k+1}$ let $E_n=F_{n_k}$. Then $E_n \in \mathcal A_n$ for each $n$ and $P(A\Delta E_n) \to 0$.